# Problem with current spike in current source

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, current-source, spike

I am designing a "simple" current source using an op-amplifier. My question is how can I get rid of that current spike shown below:
[image]
Here is the schematic of the circuit:
[image]

Comment: Try pulling the gate low.  The state on startup may be partially conducting if the feedback loop is in a no-current situation.

Comment: What is driving the AD8055? In all probability what you are seeing is the drive circuitry settling.

Comment: @vir I tried, but it doesn't improve a bit. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JackCreasey, DAC is driving the op-amplifier. The signal generated from DAC looks ok with no spikes. I think this could not affect the operation.

Comment: MOSFET gate has a not insignificant parasitic capacitance.  This problem falls into "OpAmp driving capacitive load" category.  Recommended reading: [Ask The Applications Engineer-25: Op Amps Driving Capacitive Loads](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/ask-the-applications-engineer-25.html).

Comment: Is a 1 ns overshoot a real problem?

Comment: May i know the value of voltage coming at A8055 Non inverting Pin? or the P/N of the device you are using to drive the non inverting I/P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop needs to be compensated in the AC domain because it probably has a resonant point. This can be seen if you put a 0.1V AC source on the + terminal and run an AC analysis. (you'll probably see a roll off from the main bandwidth and then a spike in magnitude when looking at a mag. vs freq. chart).

What can you do about it?

Constrain the bandwidth of the system by creating a low pass filter in the feedback pathway of the control loop. Here are a few ways I've done this in the past (the one on the right usually works better)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f45WQz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the problem is caused by the settling of the power rails as the device is turned on.
The AD8005 is not rail to rail, and initially cannot hold the gate of the NX7002 low.
Pre-biasing the OA1 output drive will help.

A change such as this may avoid the problem:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2finf96.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that you may need to use 2 diodes.